# Angular 6: How to randomly display an element (Math.random() inside *ngIf)

Tags: angular

Inside an *ngFor loop, I want an HTML element to randomly display itself...50/50 chance.

Here is what I thought would work:

```
<span *ngIf="Math.random() < 0.5">test</span>
```

But I get error:

```
BookingPageComponent.html:139 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'random' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong and how should it be done correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math` class is not available on evaluated expressions, but are available inside your component class.

So you can create a method:

```
public showRandomly(bias) {
    return Math.rand() < bias;
}
```

Then use it in your ngIf:

```
<span *ngIf="showRandomly (0.5)">test</span>
```

Note that this random will run every view refresh and might not give you the expected result.

Comment: This does work but i get console errors: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError....otherwise exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: That won't happen on production, as won't be a problem. Angular checks values changes twice when on development to check for changes outside change detection, but that's not what's happening here, just a false positive.

Comment: If you still want to avoid this, you can cache the random value on some property and avoid this. Also this will change the behavior: current code will random every change happens on any components, for example if an input field is typed. Caching it, the random will run once.

Answer (score 1):

you can't run that in the template.  You can call a function in your component that calls `Math.Random`

example:

`<span *ngIf="randomMath() < 0.5">test</span>`

in your component:

`randomMath() { return Math.random() }`

Answer (score 1):

Math class is not available natively on expression but you can do like that in your TS file:
simply write

`Math: Math = Math;`

and you keep your template

```
<span *ngIf="Math.random() < 0.5">test</span>
```

But it's recommanded to add a new function like below:

```
<span *ngIf="isVisible()">test</span>
```

In your TS file:

```
ifVisible(): boolean{
    return Math.random() < 0.5; 
}
```